# WWW::Mechanize - fill in form fields with unkown name

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

With WWW::Mechanize I want to submit a form. The problem is, that every time the form loads, the input field names are different.

```
<input type="text" name="field[347483]" tabindex="1">
<input type="text" name="field[938377]" tabindex="2">
```

The only thing I know in advance is the tabindex, not the number between [ and ].

Is there a way to fill in the fields with their tabindex? Or is there some way to tell it to "use the first field named field[*]" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

`WWW::Mechanize` uses the [`HTML::Form`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) module to process forms in the page. That module doesn't extract the `tabindex` attribute, so you have no access to it when using Mechanize

However, a call to `$mech->forms` will return a list of `HTML::Form` obiects for the page, which have an `inputs` method that returns a list of input objects for the form

If a list of input names (which may not be in `tabindex` order) is a help to you, then you can do what you want this way

Unfortunately your requirement is vague, so it is hard to show some example code